# Following with rule - `"if" statement needs to call a function instead of having a body' - I stuck by choosing between 3 approaches

Tags: php, if-statement

How to write code without `if` body and call a function instead for better readability. Each approach as I think has disadvantages

1. Unnecessary `else` word. I can complete this without `else`
2. A ternary operator used for returning value. It seems clean, but is it right using ternary operator without returning value?
3. Every time I need to repeat the keyword `return`. Seems not so clean; Unlike the 1. approach this approach has only 1 branch. And calling b() seems clean, unlike the 1 approach.

I'm stuck with this. I want to write clean code but I don't know what to choose.
Maybe do you know a better way than these 3 approaches? Or can you argue which approach in what situation to use?

1.

```
 if ($contidition) {
        a();
    } else {
        b();
    }
```

2. 

```
$contidition ? a() : b();
```

3. 

```
if ($contidition) {
    a();
    return;
}

b();
```

Comment: This entirely depends on the context, and what you're trying to accomplish. And sometimes to personal coding style/taste. Please provide a more specific situation (although this is not the most appropriate kind of question for SO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your question. If you want to put something in the `if` statement but not in the `else` statement you can just say:

```
if a != b {print(a)}
```

You don't have to write `else`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but then I need to write this:
`if ($contidition) {
        a(); }`

`if (!$contiditon) {
   b();
}`

Seems clean, but I check the same think twice.